# Tkinter Python update labels in function outside of class

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on an application which will show a lot of information.
The information which needs to be shown are return values of functions.

The main screen / window is build up from a class, but before the main screen is shown, there is a splash screen shown during the loading of some info:

```
def updateLabel(window):
    window.mainInfoLabel['Text']='New text'

def setmainScreen(main):
    mainInfoFrame = tk.LabelFrame(
      main,
      text='Information: ',
      width=700
    )
mainInfoFrame.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
mainInfoLabel=tk.Label(mainInfoFrame,text='Information:')
mainInfoLabel.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
Button=tk.Button(mainInfoFrame,text='run test',command=updateLabel(main))
testButton.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)

## CLASSES
class Splash(tk.Toplevel):
   def __init__(self, parent):
       tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
       self.title("Splash")
       self.geometry("400x200")
       self.overrideredirect(True)
       self.label=Label(self,text="Please wait while we are loading the application")
       self.label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    
    ## required to make window show before the program gets to the mainloop
      self.update()

class App(tk.Tk):
def configureRoot(self):
    self.resizable(False,False)
    self.title("myApp")
    self.geometry = ("800x800")
    self.minsize(700,800)

def setupRootScreen(self):
    
    self.mymenu=tk.Menu()
    self.myfilemenu=tk.Menu(self.CDSmenu,tearoff=0)
    self.myfilemenu.add_command(label='Exit',command=self.quit)
    self.mymenu.add_cascade(label='File',menu=self.filemenu)

def __init__(self):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)
    
    self.withdraw()
    splash = Splash(self)

    ## setup stuff goes here
    self.configureRoot()
    self.setupRootScreen()
            
    #### Do the loading stuff here...
    time.sleep(2) #this is just to simulate loading

    ## finished loading so destroy splash
    splash.destroy()

    ## show window again
    self.deiconify()
    setmainScreen(self)
    

# MAIN        
if __name__ == "__main__":
  root = App()
  root.config(menu=root.mymenu)
  root.mainloop()
```

This works fine. the function setmainScreen(self) creates a frame with a label and button inside, with the main window as parent. This all works
However, if I press the button I want to change the text of label. The application will have many labels, hence I would like to do this in external functions, outside of the APP class, but for the question, one label is enough.

However, when the button if pressed I receive the error:

```
_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'mainInfoLabel'
```

So passing the mainwindow from setmainScreen(main) to updateLabel(window) does not work, or the widgets are not recognized.
So I'm doing something wrong obviously. Not even sure if it's possible to do it this way?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you in advance

Comment: The code in the question is not formatted correctly. It would be easier to help if it was formatted the same as you have it.

Comment: What do you mean with code is not formatted correctly?

Comment: The indentation is wrong. E.g. `def configureRoot...` is not indented deeper than `class App...`. Python would see a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

At no point do you set `window.mainInfoLabel`, so the message is literally correct. You are trying to set a key in a dictionary that doesn't exist. Somewhere before calling `updateLabel` you will need to do something like:

```
window.mainInfoLabel = {} # or whatever object it needs to be.
```

As an aside, I'm not sure that inheriting from tk.Tk is the best style. Better to have an App object that has the main window as an attribute, then all of your application variables don't risk hiding existing Tk names. You would also get more helpful error messages like "'App' object has no attribute 'mainInfoLabel'"

Comment: mainInfoLabel=tk.Label(mainInfoFrame,text='Information:') Is where I create the label on the main window....or?

Comment: That doesn't assign it as an attribute of your window object.